# Groovy scripts on windows

Tags: groovy

Am am trying to automated some of my work using groovy scripts on windows. I figured that this would be great start to learning groovy. Most of the part I use groovy to execute tedious CMD commands however I have few issued that are bugging me.

First one is that I can't find a way to terminate groovy script say:

```
if (!new File('c:\\myDir').exists)
```

Seconds - problem

```
"cmd /c doStuff".execute()
```

now I read that this is a good and short way to execute commands on CMD but i peaked at the source code and every 'execute()' method is marked as deprecated, but my biggest problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to stream the results in real time of e.g.:

```
println 'cmd /c mvn clean install'.execute(null, new File('sourcePath')).text
```

this statement only prints out results once the whole build is complete. So is there any solution for this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
def p = 'cmd /c mvn clean install'.execute(null, new File('sourcePath'))
p.consumeProcessOutput( System.out, System.out )
p.waitFor()
```